# What's the equivalent of this degree in Europe and USA?

Tags: university, degree

I'm an undergraduate student in mathematics at the University of Buenos Aires. The name of the degree is "licenciatura en Matemática", which is a 5 year long degree. To graduate you must make a small work called "thesis".
Now while the degree is about mathematics, you can choose between two orientations, in the third year: pure and applied.

If you understand spanish: http://cms.dm.uba.ar/academico/carreras/licenciatura/

Comment: It sounds like a US Master's to me. The most standard time for that would be 4 + 2 years (Bachelor's + Master's) but 5-year combined programs exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The University of Cambridge's [International Qualifications page](http://www.graduate.study.cam.ac.uk/international-students/international-qualifications) recognizes a "Licenciado with an overall grade of between 8 and 9 out of 10" as "At least a 2i honours degree from a UK university or an equivalent standard from an overseas university", but also says that it's equivalent to a Singaporean Master's degree. I'd guess that most universities would consider it definitely equivalent to a Bachelors and probably also a Masters degree.